# Atualizando vários registros ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma lista com o id e email de cada usuario

> ```
> id  email
> 1   ana@gmail.com  
> 2   maria@gmail.com  
> 3   joao@gmailcom  
> ...
> ```

Como monto uma instrução sql pra atualizar todos os e-mails de uma vez só na minha tabela usuarios?

Minha tabela:

> ```
> usuarios
>   id          
>   nome        
>   sobrenome   
>   telefone    
>   email
> ```

Sei que pra atualizar um registro por vez ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET email = 'ana@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1
```

Mas como fazer com vários de uma vez?

Tentei fazer algo assim mas não deu certo:

```
UPDATE usuarios 

SET email =  
'ana@gmail.com',
'maria@gmail.com',
'joao@gmailcom'

WHERE id = 
1,
2,
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verifique se dessa forma te ajuda:

```
UPDATE usuarios
    SET email = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ana@gmail.com' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'maria@gmail.com'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'joao@gmail.com'
        ELSE id
    END
;
```

Caso seja necessário, você pode remover a cláusula **ELSE** e adicionar a cláusula **WHERE** explicitamente:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

Criei no `SQLFiddle` um exemplo baseado no que você nos passou da estrutura da sua tabela, e adequei com a resposta do [@escapistabr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69763/escapistabr) para que você possa verificar se atende sua necessidade.

> Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `sobrenome` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nome`, `sobrenome`, `telefone`, `email`) VALUES
  ('1', 'ana', 'fulana', '12345678', ''),
  ('2', 'maria', 'beltrana', '87654321', ''),
  ('3', 'joao', 'ciclano', '14785236', '');
```

> Update

```
SET email = CASE id
             WHEN 1 THEN 'ana@gmail.com' 
             WHEN 2 THEN 'maria@gmail.com'
             WHEN 3 THEN 'joao@gmail.com'
            END
WHERE id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Adicionei um comentário no `SQLFiddle` para caso você queria realizar o teste do update você retirar o comentário do update pois o mesmo no sqlfiddle só executa no Schema.

[Realize seu teste: SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8d5d4/2)